# Use a secret to store sensitive data in helm kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a `secret.yaml` file inside the templates directory with the following data:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata: 
  name: appdbpassword
stringData:
  password: password
```

I also have a ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: appdbconfigmap
data:
  jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@proxy:service
  username: bhargav
```

I am using the following pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: expense-pod-sample-1
spec:
  containers:
    - name: expense-container-sample-1
      image: exm:1
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
      args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
              name: appdbconfigmap
      env:
      - name: password
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: appdbpassword
            key: password
```

When I use the helm install command I see the pod running but if I try to use the environment variable `${password}` in my application, it just does not work. It says the password is wrong. It does not complain about the username which is a ConfigMap. This happens only if I use helm. If I don't use helm and independently-run all the YAML files using kubectl, my application access both username and password correctly.

Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 2):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  password : cGFzc3dvcmQK
```

You can also add the secret like this where converting data into base64 format. While stringData do it automatically when you create secret.

Trying Adding the secrets in environment like this way

```
envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: test-secret
```

Comment: what difference is it going to make? I guess both of them do the same thing.

Comment: @BHARGAVBEHARA both are same but you are populating environment using key name key adding whole secret instead of using key.